# Where is the time spent starting a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I've run a few commands through powershell, compiled a list of (about) average times, and I don't understand where the time is being spent.

`Measure-Command {docker run}` : ~ 50 milliseconds

`Measure-Command {node -v}` : ~ 50 milliseconds

`Measure-Command {docker run node:latest}` : ~600 milliseconds.

I would more expect the `docker run node:latest` command to be 100-200ms.

I suspect the extra time is spent checking for an updated 'latest' file but I don't know enough about the demon to be certain.

How I can get the 100-200ms load times I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker run` with no further arguments prints help text and exits.

`node -v` with no further arguments prints the version number and exits.

`docker run node:latest` has to do a number of things, including but not limited to:

- resolve `node:latest` tag to an image ID
- Load that image filesystem layer

  - In this case it seems there are no other layers, but in other cases there may be a chain of other filesystem layers to load in and compose into a final filesystem view
- Create a container
- Create read/write fs layer for the container's write/CoW operations
- Run the container
- Locate the `node` program in the container and execute it
- In this case, it just exits because there's nothing else to do
- Clean up operations on exit

Comment: Dan, I knew most of those things were happening, but my specific question was how can I mitigate some of that startup time?  Is there a way to cache the node:latest imageID?  Is there a way to speedup the image loading?  I'm really looking for the fastest possible solution for spinning up a container & shutting it down.

Comment: @MattWestlake I suppose you could use the image ID instead of `node:latest` but that cannot be adding much to the startup time... I suspect most of the time is I/O wait to read in the fs layer, setup/teardown time for the container... I think I've read that runC is more lightweight, you could look into that. But it is more low level, you would lose some things Docker brings. May not be a workable option for you.

Comment: Dan, thanks for your help.  I was able to cut the time almost in half (370ms instead of 600) buy doing a `docker run --name myProject node:latest` to "cache" the container, and then start it by doing `docker start myProject`.  Is this similar to your `docker run <imageID>` solution?

Comment: @MattWestlake No, it's different, and you've done better. `docker run` has to create a new container in order to run it. So you've basically pre-run or cached the "create" step. You might be able to do the same thing with `docker create`, which just creates a container without starting it.